# Angular Hero Tutorial - Routing - Dec 2017 - Compile Error

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't compile my code, which I've compared several times with the final code review, copy & paste...

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

But I still get the Error

`$ ERROR in C:/Users/pablues/Documents/angular-tutorial/a-t-h/src/app/heroes/heroes.component.ts (21,22): Property 'getHeroes' does not exist on type 'HeroService'.`
`ERROR in C:/Users/pablues/Documents/angular-tutorial/a-t-h/src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts (20,22): Property 'getHeroes' does not exist on type 'HeroService'.`

https://github.com/pablues/tour-of-heroes/blob/master/src/app/heroes/heroes.component.ts

https://github.com/pablues/tour-of-heroes/blob/master/src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts

https://github.com/pablues/tour-of-heroes/blob/master/src/app/hero.service.ts

I can't figure it out, where the problem is right now.

Thx in advance

Comment: your code looks fine , when you are getting the error?

Comment: as soon as I compile via `ng serve`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not see an error in HeroComponent or DashboardComponent, but there is one issue in HeroDetailComponent.

Below is your HeroService

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    // Todo: send the message _after_ fetching the heroes
    this.messageService.add('HeroService: fetched heroes');
    return of(HEROES);
  }
}
```

And below is your HeroDetailComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './hero-detail.component.css' ]
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() hero: Hero;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private heroService: HeroService,
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHero();
  }

  getHero(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.heroService.getHero(id)
      .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

> Above, **getHero(id)** is missing in your HeroService.

```
this.heroService.getHero(id).subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Problem solved. Had to add the following to hero.service.ts `getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
  // Todo: send the message _after_ fetching the hero
  this.messageService.add(`HeroService: fetched hero id=${id}`);
  return of(HEROES.find(hero => hero.id === id));
} `